# RAM and Motherboard compatibility

Tags: memory, motherboard, bios

Firstly, I apologize for my English.
It's really hard for me to write this lines;
please, understand if I'm not clear enough or 
I explained very briefly way.

My motherboard is an **Intel DX38BT**.

I have installed two memory modules, 1GB each one:

[image: **ScreenShot CPU-Z**]

I bought 2 new memory modules: Kingston 2GB PC3 - 10600 each one; not one of them works.

The code of the memory stick is **KVR13N9S6/2**; this code does not appear in **[compatibility list](http://www.kingston.com/us/memory/search/discontinuedmodels?DeviceType=0&Mfr=INT&Line=DX38BT&Model=38411)** for my mother on Kingston WebSite.

I try each one of them separately, and the PC not boot up. [The PC works perfectly with old 1GB modules]

I think that is very strange that two new memorys fails.

Additionally, I'm try with other module Kingston: **KVR13N9S8/4** which I know works perfectly; don't work either on my motherboard.

Compatibility problem?

I update the BIOS firmware to newer version, but the same issue.

In '*Memory Configuration*' on BIOS, I have:

**Memory Correction**                *Non-ECC*

**Performance Memory Profiles**      *Automatic*

I will be grateful if you can help me.

Comment: If the RAM does not appear in the supported list, why do you think it would work?

Comment: Hi, Dave. 

I read that 'compatibility list' it's a list of the memory modules which compatibility is sure, although not necessarily a list of all compatible modules.

Am I wrong?

Comment: Based on what you describe.  The memory is not supported by your motherboard. Its likely the frequency or the voltage specifications of the memory itself that is the problem.

Comment: Hi, Ramhound. I thought in the voltage.
here, the screenshot of my configuration posibilities:
http://oi59.tinypic.com/2ihxlxf.jpg
The Voltage, is one of them. Can I configure bios, for compatibility with my new memory modules?

Comment: The list is not final, I admit but I suspect it isn't compatible. Buy new RAM which is on the list

Comment: Hi, Dave. I understood that, but memory modules in compatibility list,
are labelled with: " (Discontinued) ".
I can't find those memory modules, because are not longer available.

I was wondering if I could configure BIOS for compatibility with this new memory modules.

Here: http://www.kingston.com/datasheets/kvr13n9s6_2.pdf , there are information about them.

Comment: Did you try to change Memory Correction Non-ECC to ECC ?

Comment: Hi, Davidenko. 
I try it: don't works.